# In a flutter project that uses GetX, which navigation code is better a widget or a controller?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm making a flutter app using GetX.

I want to know where to write the navigation function of GetX, between widgets and controllers.

ex) `GetX.toNamed()`, `GetX.back()`

If the widget has to handle it, how do you deliver an event from the controller to the widget when the screen needs to be moved after networking in the controller?

Comment: Its up to you and your requirements. Its flexible, You can also used in widget file  but better you can used in controller because some time you need to pass data on navigation action so contoller contain all data so you can easily do that . You can check more navigation information in there offical document. https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#route-management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple.

create another controller

and check your condition then

if true `GetX.back()` else return `null`

Example.

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      bool res = await controller.checkfun() ?? false;
      if (res) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
    child: ...
)
```

Comment: also use **GetX.back()**